# Android - Facebook API - How to authenticate two times?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, authorize

I have a problem while trying to log in on Facebook for the second time. The first time the user enter its credentials, I start to upload some pictures in the background into its Facebook account.

However, in that period, another user can come and hit the Facebook button again. I expect that the previous request is still being processed, which is the case. However, I can't get the second user to log in WHILE THE FIRST PROCESSING (that is, the upload of the pictures of the first user) HAS NOT FINISHED YET.

What happens with the current version is that, when the second user hits my Facebook button, the Facebook API just assume that it refers to the previous user (because it is still running in the background). However, I want to start ANOTHER section with this new user, while the old one is still running in the background. How can I achieve that?

Here is my simple code (when the user hits my Facebook button on the screen, I call the following method):

```
 private void uploadPictures(View target) {

    mFacebook = new Facebook(getString(R.string.facebookappid));
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
    mFacebook.authorize(this, Settings.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

PS: I have also tried to instantiate more than one Facebook and AsyncFacebookRunner objects, but it did not work (I get the same behaviour, that is, even though the objects are different, the login screen simply does not show up the second time (if the previous request is still being processed))!!!

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, you absolutely cannot do it with Official FB SDK. And I'm not entirely sure if FB's privacy policy agrees to one person having multiple accounts.

Comment: Thank you for replying. What do you mean by "one person having multiple accounts" ? I believe that is not the case here. I am trying to use the same Facebook ID to log in two or more times (with different users).

Comment: Okay, different users. Still a phone app is used by a single person. I am not too sure about this, just saying. Facebook app/ any such are (twitter,instagram..etc) designed in such a way that only one user uses it at a time. If another user use it means either the phone owner has 2 accounts OR he exchanged the phone( So, the 1st one can be signed out). Just saying my thoughts

Comment: That is the thing. This is a tablet app that goes from hand to hand (one user uses it, and passes it to another person). That is why I need to do that. But thank you for your info though. Looking forward for new ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're able to do something similar to this with the new 3.0 beta SDK. You can get it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/android/) and check out the SwitchUserSample.

You won't be able to use single sign-on (SSO) with the different users (they'll need to sign in via a webview dialog), but you'll get a different Session object that use can use for different users.